# help with IOError for reading files

Tags: python, file, directory, ioerror

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(crawlFolder):
    for file in files:
         print os.getcwd()
         f=open(file,'r')
         lines=f.readlines()
         writeFile.write(lines)
         f.close()
writeFile.close()
```

I get the error as:-

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

In reference to my partial python code above:-

print os.getcwd() --> C:\search engine\taxonomy

however, the file is located in the directory "C:\search engine\taxonomy\testFolder"

I know the error is because it works in the current directory and I need to append the directory testFolder with file somehow. Could someone please correct my code and help me out with this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `subdir` variable gives you the path from `crawlFolder` to the directory containing `file`, so you just need to pass `os.path.join(crawlFolder, subdir, file)` to `open` instead of a bare `file`.  Like so:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(crawlFolder):
    for file in files:
         print os.getcwd()
         f=open(os.path.join(crawlFolder, subdir, file),'r')
         lines=f.readlines()
         writeFile.write(lines)
         f.close()
writeFile.close()
```

Incidentally, this is a more efficient way to copy a file into another file:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(crawlFolder):
    for file in files:
         print os.getcwd()
         f=open(os.path.join(crawlFolder, subdir, file),'r')
         writeFile.writelines(f)
         f.close()
writeFile.close()
```

**[EDIT:** Can't resist the temptation to play golf:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(crawlFolder):
    for file in files:
         writeFile.writelines(open(os.path.join(crawlFolder, subdir, file)))
writeFile.close()
```

**]**